On the hypothesis of Fubini's theorem
I'm reading Bauer's Measure and Integration Theory. After the proof of Fubini's theorem in page 140 he introduces the following example:

I don´t understand why the theorem doesn't apply in this case. The set $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{R}$ is $\sigma$-finite and the function $f$ is integrable with respect to $\lambda^2 = \lambda^1 \otimes \lambda^1$. Further, he says before the example that "exceptional sets"of measure zero cannot be generally ignored when using Fubini's theorem. What is an "exceptional set"? How does it invalidate the hypothesis of the theorem?

I’m not sure what this is referring to. It is perfectly valid to use Fubini in this context.

According to what I understand, $f_{\omega_1} = \mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{R}}$ should be integrable by Fubini's theorem, but it is not.

No. Fubini only asserts that sections are integrable almost everywhere, not truly everywhere. Which is the case here as $f_{\omega_1} = 0$ is integrable whenever $\omega_1 \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ is null.

Thank you, I forgot about it completely.

@David Gao: Just a bad question regarding your answer: Why is $f_{\omega_1}$ not integrable when $\omega_{1} \in \mathbf{Q}$ ? Thanks.

@markleeds By definition of $f$, $f_{\omega_1} = 1_{\mathbb{R}}$ when $\omega_1 \in \mathbb{Q}$, and $1_{\mathbb{R}}$ is not integrable.

Because the integral of the function $\mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{R}}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is $\infty$. That means it is not intgrable.

gotcha. thanks to both of you.
